What are the hazards to this DIY RMS circuit?

I want to possilby make a DIY True RMS meter that displays RMS value on an OLED screen. It would plug into a wall and hang from the outlet.
Pretty much the AC goes to a Step-Down Power Module that's an AC DC Isolated Module; 220v to 5v. This 5 volt output would power the microprocessor (for the screen), power the Analog to Digital (ADC), and add an offset to the smaller AC wave. I think the ADC needs an all positive sine wave somewhere between 0-5 volts.
The circuit would be enclosed with a 3D print exposing only the outlet plugs and the screen.
-Vo is the ground for the ADC and OLED.
+Vo is the 5 volts.
Step-Down Power: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09Z253MQ2/
ADC: ADS1015
The wave being measured by the ACD would average at 2.5 volts and swing +/- 0.84
If this circuit is not safe, are there any minor adjustments to make it safer or is it too far off?
thank you!

running a time domain on Vo+


If you draw a proper schematic people will be more likely to review it.

If you have an isolated supply, why not isolate the measurement too? Or in other words, if you don't isolate the measurement, why use an isolated supply? Basically, the secondary 5V side now rides on 110VAC sine wave with 50k impedance, and can thus provide more than 1mA through your heart. Also why there is no fuse, and no other protection or EMI filtering for the supply input? Basically, we would need to know why the circuit looks like that, why you chose to do things like that or left out some safety features.

@Mattman944 will add to my question.

@Justme Any tips on how to isolate the measurement? How do standard RMS meters handle it? I’ve experimented with small transformers, but the ones I used constantly needed readjustment with a trimpot.

@mars91 My point exactly. If it is impossible for anyone to touch connect to live mains inside your enclosure, why even try to isolate? There may be various ways it is done. Buy a mains RMS meter and tear it apart to see how it works. Or if you do buy one, you could keep using it.

@Justme I just figured isolation would be safer, even if the circuit is enclosed. If your advice is to break apart an RMS meter to learn, that’s valid.

I would use two small 1W, doubly insulated 220V-to-4.5V transformers, or similar, connected in parallel to 220V.

One transformer would power a standard rectifier + filter followed by a buck converter to supply the MCU, display and ADC.

Another would provide a safe, stepped-down AC voltage that can be measured with the ADC.


For example:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

In my experience ordinary low power transformer will have +-10% ratio tolerance, maybe even 20% if they are really cheap. Not sure how precise measurement OP wants.

I think that true RMS measurement needs both voltage and current sensing?

thank you Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica, I will try to digest this soon. Could this be accomplished with two of the Amazon Step-Down Power modules? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09Z253MQ2/
@kiwiron I just want RMS voltage

@kiwiron No, it doesn't, not unless you want to measure both RMS voltage and RMS current.

Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica, Thanks again for the simulation! When I run it, ADCIN shows a constant 5 volts. Is there a node where I could find a small (possibly positive) AC wave for the ADC to measure?

I was able to figure it out by adding a 170-amplitude sine wave to the simulation.
My issue with transformers is that I experimented with the ZMPT101B Voltage Transformer Module, but it kept falling out of adjustment. I had to recalibrate the trimpot every few days to correct it, which isn’t ideal for a 3D-printed enclosure.
